# Display conceptual data model weak entity in PlantUML

Tags: uml, entity-relationship, plantuml, powerdesigner

How would I go about displaying this relationship in PlantUML?

[image: PowerDesigner screenshot]

I cannot figure out how to show that the entity type Foo is weak using PlantUML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UML equivalent would be a composition, something like:

```
@startuml
Bar *-- Foo
@enduml
```